# SQL Server multiple left joins with multiple inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have multiple tables as shown below where i want to get the:

```
Engine.ename
Sum of FuelConsumption.quantity
Sum of Maintainance.pricetotal
Sum of CounterHistory.total
```

Grouped by `Engine.ename`

where `Engine.ename` should be always selected along with zero values of other variables if their selection return null.

I tried this but failed, I'm getting all `Engine.ename` values but with wrong numbers along:

```
SELECT DISTCINT
    e.ename, 
    ISNUll(SUM(ch.total), 0), 
    ISNUll(SUM(fc.quantity), 0), 
    ISNUll(SUM(m.pricetotal), 0)
FROM 
    Engine e
LEFT JOIN 
    FuelConsumption fc ON fc.engineid = e.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    Maintenance m ON m.engineid = e.id 
LEFT JOIN
    (ElectricBox eb
JOIN 
    ECounter ec ON ec.boxid = eb.ID
JOIN
    Registration r ON r.counterid = ec.ID
JOIN
    CounterHistory ch ON ch.regid = r.id) ON eb.engineid = e.id
GROUP BY
    e.ename
```

Check my DB diagram below:

[image: My Diagram]

Comment: A picture of your design is unlikely to help us here. Post your database design as DDL (`CREATE`) statements. Then, to with that, post DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data and then show us the results you're expecting for that sample data. I'm afraid that what you are after here isn't clear.

Comment: @MohammadFneish . . . Your question is titled something about multiple joins.  You have a query with multiple joins that looks well-formed.  I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i think my question is clear, i need to get results grouped by Engine.ename even if the right side of the join returns no value, the above query is working but returning wrong numbers, i really appreciate your comment so please let me know if i can provide more information

Comment: @Larnu i think that the provided information could be enough to understanding my issue where it is equivalent to the create query and can also provide better visual understanding, i will make sure to provide your suggestions in the question if i don't get an answer in the upcoming few hours, thanks

Comment: You've had 2 people (*experts* in this field) say you're question isn't clear here. Without being rude, are you sure it is? Most likely the reason you've had no answers yet is because the volunteers here don't understand. Take a step back, have another read of your question as if you were trying to answer it. Could you?

Comment: @Larnu sure i can and i will, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem through joining two select statements like this:

```
Select A as EngineName, totalInvoice, fcQuantity, maintain From (

(select e.ename as 'A', ISNUll(SUM(fc.quantity),0) as fcQuantity, ISNUll(SUM(m.pricetotal),0) as maintain
FROM Engine e
    left Join FuelConsumption fc on fc.engineid = e.id 
    left Join Maintenance m on  m.engineid = e.id 
Group By e.ename) t1
left Join
(select e.ename as 'B', ISNUll(SUM(ch.total),0) as totalInvoice
FROM Engine e
Left Join ElectricBox eb On eb.engineid = e.id
        Left join ECounter ec on ec.boxid = eb.ID
                Left join Registration r on r.counterid=ec.ID
                    Left join CounterHistory ch on ch.regid = r.id
Group By e.ename) t2

On t1.A = t2.B)
```

Thanks all